# How can I test laravel job's second try logic which is using attempts function

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-jobs

I have a queued job class which backs off exponentially thanks to the `backoff()` method. I want to test that `backoff()` method works right. It should create `2, 4, 8, 16` and so on after each retry. Since `attempts()` function belongs to the `InteractsWithQueue` trait and reads the attempt count from the deeper `RedisJob` class' `decoded` payload, I could not find a proper way to test this.

Any help?

```php
class AJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 10; 

    public function backoff()
    {
        return pow(2, $this->attempts());
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        try{
            //Some logic
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $this->release($this->backoff());
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. Here is the solution.

```php
public function test_backoff_after_fifth_attempt()
    {
        /** @var RedisJob $mockRedisJob */
        $mockRedisJob = $this->mock(
            RedisJob::class,
            function (MockInterface $mock) {
                $mock->shouldReceive('attempts')->once()
                     ->andReturn(5);
            }
        );

        $job = new SendMailJob(new Mail());
        $job->setJob($mockRedisJob);

        $this->assertEquals(32, $job->backoff());
    }
```